# Passing variable value in sql query using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Let us suppose I have a sql query

```
     Select abc from table1 where abc > 100
```

I want value of 100 to be derived from textbox 
Can anyone tell me how to do this in jsp?

Comment: could you please be bit more clear

Comment: Basically in jsp i want to pass the value of texbox into sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post the form to servlet

```
<form action="YourServlet">
  <input type="text" name="data">
</form>
```

on servlet in doPost

```
request.getParameter("data");
```

**See Also**

- [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: and be careful with some nasty SQL injections